# Spring MVC with postgres and tomcat8

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbc, tomcat8

I have big issue with connecting my spring mvc application to postgres database using JDBC. I have this exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc::postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:437)
at pl.jsoftworks.gymtracker.restapi.TestController.jdbc(TestController.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2403)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2392)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for    jdbc::postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
... 42 more
```

I know there is a lot of topics on that matter, but non is working for me :(

I got postgresql driver in the lib directory of tomcat:

```
 Katalog: c:\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\lib

 2014-11-19  22:40    <DIR>          .
 2014-11-19  22:40    <DIR>          ..
 2014-09-24  21:03            17 351 annotations-api.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            52 623 catalina-ant.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           122 569 catalina-ha.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            71 773 catalina-storeconfig.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           253 103 catalina-tribes.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03         1 492 249 catalina.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03         2 298 872 ecj-4.4.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            81 148 el-api.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           160 117 jasper-el.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           587 349 jasper.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            61 051 jsp-api.jar
 2014-11-16  14:15           592 322 postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           244 101 servlet-api.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03             8 971 tomcat-api.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           695 816 tomcat-coyote.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           237 352 tomcat-dbcp.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            68 092 tomcat-i18n-es.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            41 480 tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            43 631 tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           134 172 tomcat-jdbc.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            64 952 tomcat-jni.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            54 501 tomcat-spdy.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           197 974 tomcat-util-scan.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           101 324 tomcat-util.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03           198 771 tomcat-websocket.jar
 2014-09-24  21:03            36 640 websocket-api.jar
```

I added ths code to tomcat conf/context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/myapp"
          username="gtclient" password="zaqwsx" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
```

and this go into my web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>postgreSQL Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/postgres</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

here is my servlet bean cfg:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc::postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp"/>
    <property name="username" value="gtclient"/>
    <property name="password" value="zaqwsx"/>
</bean>
```

Do You guys have any idea what Im doing wrong? I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a wild guess here:

In your datasource bean you have connection string as `jdbc::postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp`. It should probably be `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp` (only a single colon after jdbc).

Comment: Yeah, this was it, stiupid typo took so much time from my life... there should be validator for that kind of things. Big thanks.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk These errors caused by small typos happen to everyone from time to time, they are the most annoying problems because you spend most time trying to solve them and in the end you just realize you need to change one character to do so :). By the way if this solution worked for you could you please mark this answer as Accepted? Thanks :)